# yum install clamtk says no package clamtk available

Tags: yum, clamav

I've looked through the yum install no package available different answers and I haven't found an answer. I'm following a tutorial and it said to run

```
sudo yum install clamtk
```

However when I run that I get this:

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * epel: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * updates: repos.lax.quadranet.com
No package clamtk available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

the no package clamtk available error, I'm not sure why I'm getting that. I'm new to this so I'm confused as to why it doesn't install.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just downloading the package from their repository online.  Then I ran yum localinstall file name.